# Why was Not Safe for Work repremiered as Clipaholics?

Tags: production

A long while ago, a new TV show called *Not Safe for Work* premiered on truTV. It was a total crap show and I didn't enjoy a moment of the two episodes that aired. Apparently a lot of people agreed because after the second episode, the show seemed to have completed vanished off the face of the Earth.

Recently, a new show called *Clipaholics* premiered on truTV which appears to be the same exact thing. Same ideas, same style and theme, and even some of the same exact videos. I didn't bother watching any of it because, well, it looked like the same *Not Safe for Work* show that I hated before.

Does anyone know the reasoning behind the cancellation of the original series, *Not Safe for Work*, and the sprouting of the "new" and renamed series, *Clipaholics*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it seems to be the same show. (And it does look like trash.) The only "official" word I could find was from the [Clipaholics twitter feed](http://twitter.com/#!/clipaholics) which tweeted

> No new episode this week -- we'll be back with an all-new clip show next Thursday at 10pm (e/p)!

(2 May 2012)

> Also, we're changing our name up and everything else about the show. Stay tuned! You can get up to the minute updates here on Twitter.

(2 May 2012)

It's nothing conclusive, but it seems like it was taken off briefly and re-tooled, probably due to a negative response. There doesn't seem to be any journalism covering this because it's such a minor show. I'm not sure why they changed the name but my guess is that the phrase "Not Safe For Work" has such a strong presence on the Internet already that it wasn't being associated with the show.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the truth.  TruTV ruined the original concept behind "Not Safe For Work".  Development was very slow and had very little backing from network execs... combine that with horrid ratings after week two... Tru won the battle against the creative team and made them re-tool it to a more similar "Top 20" format.  Yes, for the first few weeks you'll see that many of the clips will be the same and it will feel unoriginal.  All I can say is that the original cuts of NSFW 101-107 were incredibly hilarious and well written until Tru began tweaking and cutting out all of the comedy.